# Problem on starting a fresh api-platform project with docker compose

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I just downloaded the api-platform starting project, as suggested using the tar.gz file, then run `docker compose up` and I get this error:

> ERR_PNPM_FROZEN_LOCKFILE_WITH_OUTDATED_LOCKFILE  Cannot perform a frozen installation because the version of the lockfile is incompatible with this version of pnpm

Anyone faced the same issue?

I tried to change the Dockerfile by setting an older pnpm version (7.25.0) but with no luck, the error i received was:

> ERR_PNPM_NO_IMPORTER_MANIFEST_FOUND  No package.json (or package.yaml, or package.json5) was found in "/srv/app".

Comment: If you are facing a problem with code provided by others, please ask them for help. Such a starting project usually has a repository with an issue tracker, and that's where you should file a bug. The error message doesn't even look related to PHP to me